# How to get the ID of a User by its username using JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I was making a discord bot and to make a command for it to ban a user, I found that this line of code works fine. However, to ban the user, it needs the ID.
Code:

```
message.getGuild().ban(args[1], 0).queue();
// Args[1] is the ID of the user needed to be banned
// message is the argument in onMessageRecieved
```

I want that it should work when given the name of the user.
For eg:
When I type !-ban Someone#1234 (!- is the prefix) it should ban the user.
Is there any separate command to ban the user by its username? if not, can I get the ID of the user by the username?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `guild.retrieveMembersByPrefix(...)` <sup>[[1]](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMembersByPrefix(java.lang.String,int))</sup> to get members by name, which you can then filter again to get the exact user you want to ban. This only works if the user is actually a member of the guild, discord does not offer any way to get IDs based on just the name.

```java
// name is just the username (without the discriminator #1234)
guild.retrieveMembersByPrefix(name, 100).onSuccess(members -> {
  // members is a list of members for the given name
  Member member = members.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getUser().getAsTag().equals(usertag)) // filter by Name#Discrim like Someone#1234
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
  if (member != null)
    member.ban(0).queue();
  else
    System.out.println("Couldn't find a member with that name");
});
```

Comment: In the code you gave, it gave an error because there were two variables of the same name (member), one in Member member = members.stream and the other one of filter(member ->).  So I replaced member with q at filter(member -> member.getUser()) to make it filter(q -> q.getUser()).
However, after this, the code won't won't ban the user.